# How to pass focus props in components VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have component child `Input`:

```js
<template>
  <div class="basic-input-outer" :style="styles">
    <p class="paragraph-small">{{ title }}</p>
    <input ref="name" :type="type" class="basic-input">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Input",
  props: ['type', 'styles', 'title', 'focus'],
  watch: {
    focus: function() {
      this.setFocus()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setFocus() {
      this.$refs.name.focus()
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "../assets/css/components/Input";
</style>
```

And I have parent component where I work with this input:

```js
   <div class="login-options">
     <p class="choose" @click="chooseLogin('email')">With Email</p>
     <div class="vertical-line" />
     <p class="choose" @click="chooseLogin('phone')">With Phone Number</p>
   </div>

   <div v-if="loginWithEmail">
    <Input :focus="emailFocus" :title="'Email'" :type="'email'" />
   </div>
   <div v-else>
     <Input :focus="phoneFocus" :title="'Phone number'" :type="'email'" />
   </div>

...

chooseLogin(option) {
  if (option === 'email') {
    this.loginWithEmail = true
    this.emailFocus = true
  } else {
    this.loginWithEmail = false
    this.phoneFocus = true
  }
}
```

So, the problem is, when I trigger the function it only focuses one time on one field, and then stops. I want to make that `focus` props works that way, so when it's triggered, the field will be focused, and it will be working not just one time, like in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution. Actually, it was because `v-if`. `v-if` just remove element(-s) from DOM, so, the best way to solve such problems is to use conditional styling with `display: none`:

`Input`:

```js
<template>
  <div class="basic-input-outer" :style="styles">
    <p class="paragraph-small">{{ title }}</p>
    <input ref="name" :type="type" class="basic-input">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Input",
  props: ['type', 'styles', 'title', 'focus'],
  watch: {
    focus: function() {
      if (this.focus) this.$refs.name.focus()
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "../assets/css/components/Input";
</style>
```

And parent component:

```
<Input :style="[!loginWithEmail ? {'display': 'none'} : {'': ''}]" :focus="emailFocus" :title="'Email'" :type="'email'" />
<Input :style="[loginWithEmail ? {'display': 'none'} : {'': ''}]" :focus="phoneFocus" :title="'Phone number'" :type="'email'" />

...

    chooseLogin(option) {
      if (option === 'email') {
        this.loginWithEmail = true
        this.emailFocus = true
        this.phoneFocus = false
      } else {
        this.loginWithEmail = false
        this.emailFocus = false
        this.phoneFocus = true
      }
    }
```